# Sorting a pandas DataFrame by one level of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndexed pandas DataFrame that needs sorting by one of the indexers. Here is a snippet of the data:

```
gene                      VIM  
treatment dose time            
TGFb      0.1  2    -0.158406  
          1    2     0.039158  
          10   2    -0.052608  
          0.1  24    0.157153  
          1    24    0.206030  
          10   24    0.132580  
          0.1  48   -0.144209  
          1    48   -0.093910  
          10   48   -0.166819  
          0.1  6     0.097548  
          1    6     0.026664  
          10   6    -0.008032
```

I'm looking to sort the data so that the time index is in ascending order. My first thoughts was to use `pandas.sort_values` but it seems this doesn't work on the index. Does anybody know of a way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sort_index` specifying `level`:

```
df.sort_index(level=2)
```

Or

```
df.sort_index(level=-1)
```

Or

```
df.sort_index(level='time')
```

All yield:

[image]

Comment: For my case, I found I needed to add `sort_remaining=False` to preserve the order of subsequent levels (in the OP's case, imagine having another index column after `time` whose order you want to preserve)